# I would require assistance in implementing a small logic

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
SELECT id,value from table LIMIT 10;

ID                      VALUE
01183660                Item Info, List
01183661                Item Info, List
01183662                Item Info, List
41183664                Item Info, List
41183665                Item Info, List
41183666                Item Info, List
41183667                Item Info, List
41183668                Item Info, List
41183669                Item Info, List
41183670                Item Info, List
```

I need to remove the spaces after comma in the VALUE column. TRIM will remove the spaces at the beginning and end.

Comment: Please make sure the title of your questions actually expresses the issue you're having.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Item Info, List', ', ', ',');
```

I get back:

```
Item Info,List
```

Comment: I tried using REPLACE and it worked perfectly.